# Create columns of a pandas dataframe from other columns containing data in text format

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have the following dataframe

```
data= {
    'a_index':[55, 72, 112, 55, 53, 100, 89],
    'make':['TY', 'FD', 'TA', 'HA', 'MA', 'BW', 'VN'],
    'p_index':[120, 70, 120, 128, 180, 172, 150],
    'score':['2.3,1.3,3.2,3.4','2.7,4.3, 4.2,3.4','2.3,4.3, 4.2,,3.4', '2.3,4.3, 4.2,3.4', '1.3,5.3, 7.2,3.4', '2.3,4.3, 4.2,3.4', '2.3,4.3,4.2,3.4'],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,
                  index=['NK', 'JN', 'NA', 'PP', 'DK', 'HA', 'CK'])
df
```

which gives me

```
    a_index make  p_index   score
NK  55      TY     120      2.3,1.3,3,2,3.4
JN  72      FD     70       2.7,4.3, 4,2,3.4
NA  112     TA     120      2.3,4.3, 4,2,,3.4
PP  55      HA     128      2.3,4.3, 4,2,3.4
DK  53      MA     180      1.3,5.3, 7,2,3.4
HA  100     BW     172      2.3,4.3, 4,2,3.4
CK  89      VN     150      2.3,4.3,4,2,3.4
```

What is the easiest way to the following dataframe from this dataframe

```
    a_index make    p_index score             sore_1    sore_2  sore_3  sore_4
NK   55     TY      120      2.3,1.3,3,2,3.4    2.3     1.3     3.2      3.4
JN   72     FD      70       2.7,4.3, 4,2,3.4   2.7     4.3     4.2      3.4
NA   112    TA      120      2.3,4.3, 4.2,3.4   2.3     4.3     4.2      3.4
PP   55     HA      128      2.3,4.3, 4.2,3.4   2.3     4.3     4.2      3.4
DK   53     MA      180      1.3,5.3, 7,2,3.4   1.3     5.3     7.2      3.4
HA   100    BW      172      2.3,4.3, 4.2,3.4   2.3     4.3     4.2      3.4
CK   89     VN      150      2.3,4.3,4.2,3.4    2.3     4.3     4.2      3.4
```

Comment: instead of  `2.3,4.3, 4,2,,3.4` should be `2.3,4.3, 4,2, 3.4`?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Corrected.

Comment: @kederrac, Ukrainian-serge and  Samira Kumar thank you for your time and answering my question. Appreciate it. All three work for the latest pandas version.  I have upvoted all three answers but can accept only one answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use:

```
pd.concat(
    [
        df, 
        df['score'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(
            lambda x: f'score_{x}',axis='columns')
    ], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: u could replace the rename section with ... add_prefix('score_')

Comment: but is more readable using rename with axis=`columns` there are many ways to do it, and I guess is subjective

Comment: Great. This worked perfectly with latest version of pandas. I liked your solution. But how can we write the same functionality in pandas ``0.17``? This is the version of pd I use in prod.

Comment: @Ayalew thx, but as I was saying this is a task for another question

Answer (score 3):

You can try using this.

```
df['score'].str.split(',').apply(pd.Series).rename(columns = {0:'score_1',1:'score_2',2:'score_3',3:'score_4'})
```

```
    score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4
NK  2.3 1.3 3.2 3.4
JN  2.7 4.3 4.2 3.4
NA  2.3 4.3 4.2 3.4
PP  2.3 4.3 4.2 3.4
DK  1.3 5.3 7.2 3.4
HA  2.3 4.3 4.2 3.4
CK  2.3 4.3 4.2 3.4
```

and then merge it back to original dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
exploded = df.score.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(',')))       # use explode

exploded.columns = ['score_'+str(col) for col in exploded.columns] # rename columns

pd.concat([df, exploded], axis=1)                                  # concat to original df
```

```
print(df)

    a_index make  p_index             score score_0 score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4
NK       55   TY      120   2.3,1.3,3,2,3.4     2.3     1.3       3       2     3.4
JN       72   FD       70  2.7,4.3, 4,2,3.4     2.7     4.3       4       2     3.4
NA      112   TA      120  2.3,4.3, 4,2,3.4     2.3     4.3       4       2     3.4
PP       55   HA      128  2.3,4.3, 4,2,3.4     2.3     4.3       4       2     3.4
DK       53   MA      180  1.3,5.3, 7,2,3.4     1.3     5.3       7       2     3.4
HA      100   BW      172  2.3,4.3, 4,2,3.4     2.3     4.3       4       2     3.4
CK       89   VN      150   2.3,4.3,4,2,3.4     2.3     4.3       4       2     3.4
```

Comment: This is great. Do you know how to do the same with pandas 0.17

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your version of Python. When I have time I'll create a `Python 2.7` `env` and post solution.